# Request de objeto json sempre retornando NULL em php

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando acessar um servidor e enviar dados/ receber retorno em objeto json com a linguagem php.

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8; Accept:application/json; Accept-Language:en-US');
```

Pra começar, configurei o header,  a 1ª tentativa foi usando `file_get_contents`:

```
//Acesso ao web service
$json_string = file_get_contents('https://111.222.333.444/v1/activateCode');

$parsed_json =json_decode($json_string, true);
echo $parsed_json;

//tentativa falhada de decodificar a string em formato utf-8
$parsed_json = utf8_decode($parsed_json);

var_dump($http_response_header);
```

o retorno é `NULL`, então a 2ªtentavia foi:

```
//url com declaracao de variaveis
$url="https://111.222.333.444/v1/activateCode?code=0000002381237220&amount=10.00&upc=799366838258&transactionID=1317828766162&dateTime=2015-05-28T11:32:46.162Z";

//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump a beauty json :3
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
$result = utf8_decode($result);
```

Retorno NULL tambem..., então a 3ªtentativa foi:

```
//Acesso ao web service
$json_string = file_get_contents('https://111.222.333.444/v1/activateCode');

$parsed_json =json_decode($json_string, true);

//declarações das variaveis do activateCode
$code = "0000002381237220";
$amount = "10.00";
$upc = 799366838258;
$transactionID = 1317828766162;
$dateTime = "2015-05-28T11:32:46.162Z";
$retailerName = "XYZ";

if( is_null($parsed_json) ){
    // Invalid JSON, don't need to keep on working on it
    echo "<br/>======INICIO NULO=======<br/>";
    echo "codigo nulo";
    echo "<br/>======FIM NULO=======<br/>";
}else{
    // Read data
    echo "<br/>=======RETORNO DA TRANSAÇAO============<br/>";
    echo "RetailTransactionRequest is:";
    echo $parsed_json->alerts[0]->code;
    echo $parsed_json->alerts[0]->amount;
    echo $parsed_json->alerts[0]->upc;
    echo $parsed_json->alerts[0]->transactionID;
    echo $parsed_json->alerts[0]->dateTime;
    echo $parsed_json->alerts[0]->retailerName;
}
```

Que me retorna somente a frase:
`>=======RETORNO DA TRANSAÇAO============<br/>RetailTransactionRequest is:` sem nenhuma variavel retornando do servidor... e outra ali na ultima parte ja tentei setar o $ da chamada da variável (exemplo `echo $parsed_json->alerts[0]->$upc;`) mesmo assim, sem retorno. 
O acesso a servidor acontece ... mas só recebo `NULL`, quero saber como proceder... obrigado.

Comment: Verifique o que está vindo do servidor *antes* de tentar decodificar como JSON. Talvez não seja um JSON válido, o que explicaria esses sintomas.